# Proc Not Returning Output Parameter Value using PetaPoco

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, petapoco

If I execute this from SQL Server, I get the output parameter with no problem:

```
exec [dbo].[SelectByRecipient] @0, @1, @2, @TotalCount = @3 output
```

The output parameter returns 18.  However, if I do this from PetaPoco, the output parameter returns null.  I tried these combinations:

```
var total = new SqlParameter("TotalCount", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
total.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

var results = ctx.Query<X>("exec [dbo].[SelectByRecipient] @0, @1, @2, @TotalCount = @3 output", var0, var1, var2, total);
//var results = ctx.Query<X>("exec [dbo].[SelectByRecipient] @0, @1, @2, @@TotalCount = @3 output", var0, var1, var2, total);
//var results = ctx.Query<X>("exec [dbo].[SelectByRecipient] @0, @1, @2, @3 output", var0, var1, var2, total);
//var results = ctx.Query<X>("exec [dbo].[SelectByRecipient] @0, @1, @2, @3 out", var0, var1, var2, total);

//Blows up because total.Value is null
var totalCount = (int)total.Value;
```

The three statements I tried fail.  They were working, but I don't know what changed...  all of a sudden, I get these errors now...

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result worked once I called `ToList()`; I read somewhere that output parameters do not return the output value when the reader is still open, which had to be the case.

Comment: Fetch should be used in preference to Query anyways.

Comment: @Schotime For my own understanding, what's the difference?

Comment: Query creates a iterator block and uses yield to return the results. In other words, it will only read from the reader when you iterate over the collection. So if you only need the first one, it would only read the first one. These can be very dangerous though because they can leave connections open into views etc where the connection may have already been closed. Fetch<> calls ToList() on the Query methods so that they are evaluated and the reader can be closed immediately. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Two **at** symbols in **@@TotalCount** - isn't it a thing that preventing you to continue?

or last assumption:

```
var results = ctx.Query<X>("exec [dbo].[SelectByRecipient] @0, @1, @2, @3 = @TotalCount output", var0, var1, var2, total);
```

Comment: I tried with a single, to no avail.  Updated the example above to reflect that.  Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm not sure what you mean.. anyway, I've also tried @3 = @TotalCount output too, but no avail.  I'll update my sample.  Seems like an ADO.NET thing maybe, not necessarily a PetaPoco thing...